# Laravel enclose the column value with apostrophe

Tags: laravel

I am getting an error while storing the address and Geometry field.

> SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1416 Cannot get geometry
> object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field (SQL: insert into
> favorite_places (user_id, title, address, location,
> updated_at, created_at) values (1, Zoo, Riyadh Front, Riyadh Saudi
> Arabia, 46.733338 24.8414096, 2020-12-17 07:39:38, 2020-12-17
> 07:39:38))

When I see the error it shows address with comma separated `Riyadh Front, Riyadh Saudi Arabia` this whole field is one column i.e address.

How do I escape the comma separated address field.

Comment: what is the type of the address field ?

Comment: address field is text , location is point

Answer (score 0):

After hour of searching I found the solution [here](https://github.com/grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial/issues/39)

I forgot to include the SpatialTrait in the model